# Local Profile To Domain Roaming Profile Desktop background black

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, domain, user-profiles, roaming-profiles

### Intro

I've setup a Domain at my house and I want my local profiles to be a Roaming Domain Profile. This is what I did so you guys know all my steps:

Let's use the local Profile Pikachu and the Roaming profile Bulbasaur (Roaming profile has as path \server\Roaming_Profiles$\%username%)

### My Steps to copy the profile:

1. (on server)Created a share to put Roaming Profiles in (Yes Share permissions and security are allright)
2. (on client) Went on the client machine and joined the domain --> Succes
3. (on client with domain admin) Downloaded Windows Enabler 1.1 to enable the copy to button in Advanced system settings
4. (on client with domain admin)Copy the desired profile (Pikachu) to the network share I just created and name it Bulbasaur.old .
5. (on server) Now I have rights with my Domain Admin I change the Security settings to: Bulbasaur,Full Control,This folder, Subfolders and Files
6. (on server) Load the NTUSDER.DAT hive and change permissions to Bulbasaur Full Controll.
7. (on server) Unload Hive
8. (on client)Login with the bulbasaur account so it creates a profile on the share --> logout
9. (On the server with Domain admin) Takeown /r /f c:\Roaming_Profiles\Bulbasaur.V2
10. (still on the server with Domain admin) icacls  c:\Roaming_Profiles\Bulbasaur.V2 /grant administrator:F /T
11. (on server) Delete the Bulbasaur.V2 directory and rename Bulbasaur.old to Bulbasaur.V2
12. (on client)Login With bulbasaur --> login takes forever because profile is 9 GB and this is getting synced offline (just how i want it to be) --> login succesful
13. (on client) When logging in the background is black and when trying to change it nothing happens

### My problem

Everything works except changing the background + the background is black.

### Possible solution:

I found out there is a Registry Key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop and there is a registry key Wallpaper that still points to the old account Pikachu localy. Changing this registry key hasn't helped me getting a background back.
Anyone who has any idea on how to properly copy a profile like this or to change the registry key that my family can change backgrounds again.

### Details

OS PC's : Windows 7 and Windows 8
Server : Windows 2012 R2 Standard
My work: Student IT in networking

You can use terms that are harder to understand than a normal person would. I like to learn new things/terms and this would help me a lot.

### Edit 1

Apperantly there is some like problem with normal users described in this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/desktop-stuck-on-solid-colours-win-7-pro/8e034d73-fbaf-45cd-a8eb-d8329e7f47e4
So I can change the solid color of my background but no pictures, So I did as said in the tread above and deleted the TranscodedWallpaper file. but no like. Did this Server sided and localy client sided. No luck...